# SRT source in dynamic GStreamer pipline

Tags: c#, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I have a dynamic pipeline that switches between a playlist of sources (File/HTTP/RMTP/SRT) on set intervals, and outputs to an RTMP sink.

The SRT source is added in listener mode, I push to it via ffmpeg in caller mode. This works ok the first time but if I add a second SRT source anywhere my playlist, the pipeline seems to hangs when I switch to it.

No error message. The listener appears to be operational since the ffmpeg process is able to push the stream to it, but I'm getting no output from the pipeline.

Here is my pipeline graph:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.